# Reading different indexes based on current index in loop

Tags: node.js

I am trying to read different indexes from different buffers on a for loop:

```
var blockA = new Buffer("01020304050607080900", "hex");
var blockB = new Buffer("11121314151617181911", "hex");
var blockC = new Buffer("21222324252627282922", "hex");

for (var i = 0, i < blockA.length; i++) {

   var al = blockA[i];

   al ^= blockB[(i*2)+1];
   al ^= blockB[(i*2)-1];

   al ^= blockC[(i*2)+1];
   al ^= blockC[(i*2)-1];
}
```

But I guess the logic is wrong, What I'm expecting is:

```
01 ^= 12;
01 ^= 11;

01 ^= 22
01 ^= 21;
```

Next loop:

```
02 ^= 14;
02 ^= 13;

02 ^= 24;
02 ^= 23;
```

Then next:

```
03 ^= 16;
03 ^= 15; so on...
```

What is the proper way to handle this? Should I add another counter inside?

Comment: how about `(i+1)` and `(i)` instead of `(i*2)+1` and `(i*2)-1`..? and `i < blockA.length-1` inside the `for`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this computation for the index `(i*2) + 1` and `(i*2)`?